# Keyboard popup moves cursor automatically in ExpandableListView Item - Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-keypad

I have `ExpandableListView` like shown below:

I have already used ExpandableList multiple times in my app and everything works fine. But in this case `problem is that when i click input field to enter discount price or price and number keyboard popup from bottom then it push cursor to the size field automatically.`

> Basically it happens whenever keyboard popup from bottom

if I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in manifest file for this activity then it works fine but then some part of list shows behind keyboard and not visible to user unless user hide softkeyboard.

Also if i set Price `inputType` to `text` then everything works fine because keyboard popup once and then cursor doesnt jumps to other field automatically whenever i tap on price or discount field because keyboard doesnt reappear in that case.

**Summary is that if cursor is in price or discount field and keyboard popup it will automatically push the cursor to size field of that row in ExpandableList**

[image]

Comment: isn't `adjustResize` work?

Comment: @Zain I cant use `adjustResize` because of this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36947241